# Rails page caching expires_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, page-caching

In an arbitrary Rails controller will the line below work?

```
caches_page :show, :expires_in => 1.days
```

I use memcached, but am confused by how page caching works. Does it use the file system or will it put the pages in memory with memcached?

**EDIT:** it appears that it *will* use the file system. So is there a simple way to automatically release the page from cache after a given time or do I have to write a sweeper?

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807798/page-caching-with-memcached

Answer (score 3):

Rails cache method depends on your settings in application.

Check you `config/environments` directory files for `config.cache_store` option.

Official guides for caching in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html